# r.resamp.interp is not giving correct results

Tags: grass-gis, resampling

I am doing resampling uisng r.resamp.interp in GRASS GIS, but, after applying each time It reduces the size of raster. I am using this command

```
g.region raster=raster
r.resamp.interp input=raster output=resampled_raster method=bilinear
```

Original raster
[image: original image]

Resampled rater
[image: resampled image]

Comment: Typically, for interpolation, you would set the region to a resolution that is finer than the input raster. Here, you are using the same region as the input raster, so the border cells, "look" for 4 surrounding cells, and find NULL (outside the input map). Try setting the resolution with g.region to 1/2 the resolution of the input.

Comment: Alternatively, grow the computational region with `g.region grow=1` (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/g.region.html) prior to running the resampling.